# How to split select query rows based on the comma separated values in the columns in oracle plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, split

I wrote 2 queries Union. i'm getting results as comma separted in two of the columns. And the output is displayed as 2 records.

How to split them into 4 records as below expected results?

```
select emp_id,dept_name,location from department where dept_id = 1
union
select emp_id,dept_name,location from sales_dept where dept_id = 1;
```

**Output**:

```
emp_id ----- dept_name------  location

r1-----------Retail,IT-----   US, UK
k2-----------Sales,Chemical-  NZ, SA
j3-----------Biotech(Chemistry,Tech)-   JA
```

I need the **expected output** as  below:

```
emp_id ----- dept_name-----location
r1-----------Retail--------US
r1-----------IT----------- UK
k2-----------Sales---------NZ
k2-----------Chemical------SA
j3---------Biotech(Chemistry,Tech)--JA
```

The last record of whereever dept_name is "Biotech(Chemistry,Tech)" should be displayed as single record and not to be split. Please let me know how to do it.

The query given by Jim is working fine except in this scenario when dept_name is Biotech(Chemistry,Tech) as the requirement is given now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use below query,

```
select emp_id, dept_name, location from
(select distinct emp_id, trim(regexp_substr(dept_name,'[^,]+', 1, level) ) dept_name, 
trim(regexp_substr(location,'[^,]+', 1, level) ) location, level
from pivot_comma
connect by regexp_substr(dept_name, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null 
order by emp_id, level);
```

Comment: Jim the query is working fine.However, for the same output whenever the dept_name is " Biotech(Chemistry,Tech)" .That record should be displayed as single record and not to be split.   Please let me know how to do it as this is the new requirement and change needed asap.